# swift: tableview didDeselectRowAt checkmark

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

When I reload my tableview with a searchController I correctly see those users who are selected because I added them in an array (utentiSelezionati) and I performed a check. But to deselect them I have to tap two times and I can't understand why. It seems that even if it is selected, it calls didSelect method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:      "UserTableViewCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.selectionStyle = .none // to prevent cells from being "highlighted"

    if let c = cell as? UserTableViewCell {
        let utente = self.utenti[indexPath.row]

        c.textLabel?.text = utente.name
        c.detailTextLabel?.text = utente.email

        if utentiSelezionati.contains(where: {$0.id == utente.id}){
            cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .checkmark
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let utente = self.utenti[indexPath.row]

    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    if !self.utentiSelezionati.contains(where: {$0.id == utente.id}){
        self.utentiSelezionati.append(utente)
  print("premuto aggiungi") 
    }
  print("something") 
}
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none

    let utente = self.utenti[indexPath.row]

    print("premuto rimuovi")

    if let index:Int = self.utentiSelezionati.index(where: {$0.id == utente.id}) {
        self.utentiSelezionati.remove(at: index)

        print(utente.id! ," rimosso")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set `allowsMultipleSelection` to `true`?

Comment: yes I did, thanx

Comment: I think you need reload your modified indexpath in didDeselectRowAt method

Comment: can you explain me how please?

Comment: Are you able to format your code?

Comment: try comment this line `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none` and add this `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)`  below `print(utente.id! ," rimosso")`

Comment: @LorenzoB mm not sorry

Comment: @ReinierMelian if I do that the checkmark goes away at first click and that's a point! but it continues to call didSelect

Comment: @HaVaNa7 what you mean with "but it continues to call didSelect"?

Comment: @ReinierMelian that if I press in the console I see print("premuto aggiungi") that's inside didSelect...

Comment: I think that log is inside didDeselectRowAt not didSelect as your code shows, check again please and let me know @HaVaNa7

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes inside didDeselectRowAt

Comment: Then is correct that prints, so, I can post my comment as answer? @HaVaNa7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments you need remove this line `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none` from your `didDeselectRowAt` method and add this one `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)` below `print(utente.id! ," rimosso")` line

**full code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let utente = self.utenti[indexPath.row]

    print("premuto rimuovi")

    if let index:Int = self.utentiSelezionati.index(where: {$0.id == utente.id}) {
        self.utentiSelezionati.remove(at: index)

        print(utente.id! ," rimosso")
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

## Update

**Alternative**

Remove all your code from DidSelect and DidDeSelect and add this didSelect implementation only

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let utente = self.utenti[indexPath.row]

        if !self.utentiSelezionati.contains(where: {$0.id == utente.id}){
            self.utentiSelezionati.append(utente)
            print("premuto aggiungi")
        }else{
            if let index:Int = self.utentiSelezionati.index(where: {$0.id == utente.id}) {
                self.utentiSelezionati.remove(at: index)

                print(utente.id! ," rimosso")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        print("something") 
    }
```

Comment: sorry @ReinierMelian, I checked many times and the behavior its still the same, can you help me more?

Comment: I added print("something") in the code to be sure that when I reload the table if I press the cell to uncheck, it calls didSelectRowAt again..
It seems that when I reload a table the first method called at click MUST be didSelectRowAt

Comment: @HaVaNa7 check everything and if works properly please upvote my answer as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for **Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:      IndexPath) 
  {
    if (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark)
    {
      //For removing check mark     
      tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

      let utente = self.utenti[indexPath.row]
      print("premuto rimuovi")
      if let index:Int = self.utentiSelezionati.index(where: {$0.id == utente.id}) 
      {
        self.utentiSelezionati.remove(at: index)
        print(utente.id! ," rimosso")
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      // For adding checkMark
      tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

      let utente = self.utenti[indexPath.row]
      if !self.utentiSelezionati.contains(where: {$0.id == utente.id})
      {
      self.utentiSelezionati.append(utente)
      print("premuto aggiungi") 
      }
    print("something") 
    }
  }
```